# Execute script when docker container start

Tags: bash

I want container with "centos:latest" image to be started and should execute my script. The scripts are copied with docker cp commands.

```
docker create --name centos1 centos:latest
docker cp . 5db38b908880:/opt   ---> scripts are in current directory, hence .
docker commit centos1 new_centos1  --> now new_centos1 image has scripts
```

Now I want to start new container with the scripts to be executed: I tried below commands:

```
docker run -ti --rm --entrypoint "cd /opt && deploy_mediainfo_lambda.sh" new_centos1:latest

docker run -ti --rm new_centos1:latest "cd /opt && deploy_mediainfo_lambda.sh"
```

Both of above commands failed with:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:296: starting container process caused "exec: \"cd /opt && deploy_mediainfo_lambda.sh\": stat cd /opt && deploy_mediainfo_lambda.sh: no such file or directory": unknown.
ERRO[0000] error waiting for container: context canceled
```

if used bash command while starting container, I can run my script using 'execuateble path'/'execuatble name' inside container, but I can not do this while starting container on commandline

```
docker run -ti --rm new_centos1:latest bash
[root@c34207f3f1c4 /]# ./opt/deploy_mediainfo_lambda.sh
```

If used below command, which calls executable directly, it gives path error.

```
docker run -ti --rm new_centos1:latest "deploy_mediainfo_lambda.sh"

docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:296: starting container process caused "exec: \"deploy_mediainfo_lambda.sh\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.
ERRO[0000] error waiting for container: context canceled
```

Also not sure about setting $PATH from commandline while starting the container.

I know, using **Dockerfile** this is achievable, like:

1. can set path using ENV,
2. can copy executables with ADD or COPY
3. run executables using CMD or ENTRYPOINT

How to achieves it using docker commandline?

Comment: What happens if you pass `"/opt/deploy_mediainfo_lambda.sh"` as the command?

Comment: It gives below error: standard_init_linux.go:195: exec user process caused "exec format error"

Comment: What's the first line of `deploy_mediainfo_lambda.sh`?

Comment: Export statement like:export AWS_DEFAULT_OUTPUT=json

Comment: The first line should specify an interpreter, e.g. `#!/bin/bash`.

Comment: Yes, it worked. Thank you! I accept your answer.

Comment: The first  two characters #! constitutes the "magic number" that the exec() family of functions detects when they determine whether a file that they are about to execute is a script (which needs an interpreter) or a binary file (which doesn't).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks **melpomene**.

Here is my bash script to automate script execution inside container, after copying them, all using docker commands.

```
 # Start docker container
docker create --name mediainfo_docker centos:latest
# copy script files
docker cp . mediainfo_docker:/opt
# save container with the new image, which contains all scripts.
docker commit mediainfo_docker mediainfo_docker_with_scripts

# Now run scripts inside docker container
docker run -ti --rm  mediainfo_docker_with_scripts:latest /opt/deploy_mediainfo_lambda.sh
```

Since deploy_mediainfo_lambda.sh is a script, first line of it is:
 ***#!/bin/bash***